# Does google bot ignore load balancer sticky cookie?

Tags: cookies, amazon-web-services, web-crawler, session-cookies

I have setup a load balancer on AWS and have *'Enabled Application Generated Cookie Stickiness'* (As you can login to parts of the site.)

I need to know if google bot will ignore this cookie, or will it be stuck on one server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From "[Google-friendly sites](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=40349)":

> If features such as JavaScript, cookies, session IDs, frames, DHTML, or Macromedia Flash keep you from seeing your entire site in a text browser, then spiders may have trouble crawling it.

The consensus on the Web is that the **GoogleBot does not handle cookies**.

I also have a hard time understanding **why** such web crawlers would want to handle cookies.